# Replace a remote image with a local image on static web pages

Tags: image, apache-config

I have an image that displays stock quotes update on our website. This is being fed by an external site with a static path pointing to this remote image. (This image gets updated with stock info there). The updates don't happen now and I will have to remove this image on several static web pages on my site until something else is in place.
Is there a way I can over-write this image easily on all pages with a local image within the site? I was wondering if there is a way I can get this done on the site level, may be tweak the apache conf file. Any other work around suggestions.  Please let me know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `crossorigin` attribute  to get images from 3rd party websites

example:

```
<img height="100" width="100" crossorigin=anonymous src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAjTAAAAJDNlOGJiNTRkLTJhMzMtNDZlMi05NjJiLTZmMGRhODkzMzVkNw.jpg" />
```